# Is it possible to combine match statements with array destructuring in PHP to achieve something like pattern matching in functional programming?

Tags: php, functional-programming, pattern-matching, destructuring

I was hoping for something like this to work:

```
$bar = match (foo()) {
    [] => throw Exception,
    [, ] => throw Exception,
    [$x] => $x,
};
```

Where, I'd test if `foo()` gives array of exactly one element, and if it does, store that one element in `$bar`, otherwise throw an exception.

Naturally, I can accomplish this with `if` statements, but was hoping for something similar to this syntax to work.

It doesn't work both because it fails on `[, ]` with `Cannot use empty array elements in arrays` and on `$x` with `Undefined variable` - both of which is as expected.

My motivation is from functional programming where something similar would work. Is there a way to write something similar to my code above that would work?

Comment: No, pattern matching is not possible in PHP.

Comment: Specifically, I think [this is the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pattern-matching#array_structure_pattern) which last got into pattern matching

Comment: @lukas.j well of course it's possible, you just have to write a program that evaluates the patterns and consequent expressions..

Comment: @Mulan That is of course correct, but would not match – pun intended – with the question. Which is about pattern matching in functional programming and if that is possible in PHP. NigelRen below gives the perfect answer for the OP's case, but it is not 'pattern matching'. This is why the RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/match_expression_v2, which was implemented for PHP 8.0, does not call it 'pattern matching' but 'Match expression' – a better and safer version for the clumsy _switch_ statement – and specifically mentions 'pattern matching' not being part of the RFC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest I could think of would be to change the condition to use `count()` so that if matches against the number of elements.

```
$bar = match (count($a = foo())) {
    1 => current($a),
    default => throw new Exception,
};
```

It's clumsy and would thing having to have the assignment in the check as well makes it less attractive.

As mentioned in the comments on the question,

> No, pattern matching is not possible in PHP.

and

> Specifically, I think [this is the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pattern-matching#array_structure_pattern) which last got into pattern
> matching

Comment: Cool tnx! Agree it's less attractive. Maybe you can add the comment by Chris Haas about RFC - I found it useful and I can accept the answer?

Comment: @user_51 updated, usually as the comments are already on the question it isn't worth repeating them (IMHO)

Comment: Ah ok, got it on repeating, tnx anyway!